# "Be unable to do" or just "unable to do"?

Tags: difference, verbs

Is there any difference between these sentence fragments:

1. Things that will make you unable to do [this and that]
2. Things that will make you be unable to do [this and that]

Are both of them even correct? If yes, are they synonyms or there is a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that both fragments are correct, but in the second fragment 'be' is implied in this construction and would be redundant.

Comment: You're right, edited the question to include "fragments", thanks. Feel free to edit out incorrect parts yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First sentence is correct. As far as second is concerned more context is required. However first sentence's structure is more common.